# How can I make radio check box's move in any direction @media - css

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, media-queries

I am working out of wordpress, I have the CSS code for check boxes on my job board. I want those check boxes to move towards the right of the screen on a mobile device.

Reason: On iPhones, my checkboxs overlap other content and I wish to make the distant.

Job board that the radio check boxes are : https://hughesjobs.net/jobs-3

**You will see the check boxes as categories on my job board.

CSS code:

```
 .wpjb input[type=checkbox],
 .wpjb input[type=radio] {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0 ;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

Comment: float: right?  or in the container, text-align: right

Comment: Pick your media query and then put the desired CSS in there.

    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
        .wpjb input[type=checkbox],
        .wpjb input[type=radio] {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
    }

Comment: I placed the code in my theme css ...nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get what you need based on your description. But I would suggest to display them as equal width columns and rows.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { 

    #wpjb-top-search ul {
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    #wpjb-top-search ul li {
        margin: 1% 0;
        float: left;
        width: 33.33%;
        word-spacing: normal;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, It worked even in a better fashion than before.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I'd do different.
1. HTML: instead of wrapping everything in a `unordered list`, why not just have `inputs` wrapped in `labels`?
2. CSS: which then allows you to use the `label` as the `position:relative` parent and then move around the `input`

```
CSS:        
label {
            /* nothing really, inline is fine for desktop */
        }
        label input[type=checkbox] {
            /* again, inline is fine on desktop */
        }
        @media (max-width:375px){
            /* iphone 6 */
            label {
                position:relative;
                padding-right: 50px; // <== makes space for the checkbox
            }
            label input[type=checkbox] {
                /* position the checkbox to the right, with a little space on top to line up with the text. */
                position:absolute;
                right:0;
                top:3px;
            }
        }  
HTML:  
    <label for="wpjb-search-38"><input type="checkbox" class="wpjb-ls-type" name="type[]" value="38" id="wpjb-search-38"> Contractor</label>
    <label for="wpjb-search-5"><input type="checkbox" class="wpjb-ls-type" name="type[]" value="5" id="wpjb-search-5"> Freelance</label>
    <label for="wpjb-search-3"><input type="checkbox" class="wpjb-ls-type" name="type[]" value="3" id="wpjb-search-3"> Full-time</label>
    ...
```